# AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'numpy' when attempting to convert Tensor to nparray

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, type-conversion

I have been looking for a solution for this for a while but I can't seem to find anything.

Some info about my env:

```
print(tf.__version__)
print(tf.executing_eagerly())
print(tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU'))
```

Output:

```
2.7.0
True
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
```

I am using a `tf.data.Dataset` created with

```
train_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(train_dir/'*'), shuffle=False)
train_ds = train_ds.shuffle(train_count, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)

val_ds = tf.data.Dataset.list_files(str(val_dir/'*'), shuffle=False)
val_ds = val_ds.shuffle(val_count, reshuffle_each_iteration=False)
```

I then created some helper functions

```
def process_path(file_path):
  img = tf.io.read_file(file_path)
  img = decode_img(img)
  return img

def bin_image(image, mask):
    mask = mask.numpy()
    bins = np.array([20, 40, 60, 80, 100, 120, 140, 160, 180, 200, 220, 240])
    new_mask = np.digitize(mask, bins)
    new_mask_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(new_mask, np.float32)
    return image, new_mask_tensor

def split_image(image):
    cityscape = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image, 0, 0, 256, 256)
    mask = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image, 0, 256, 256, 256)
    return bin_image(cityscape, mask)
```

Using the helper functions

```
train_ds = train_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)
val_ds = val_ds.map(process_path, num_parallel_calls=AUTOTUNE)

train_images = train_ds.map(split_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
val_images = val_ds.map(split_image, num_parallel_calls=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
```

Printing the type of the mask

```
print(type(mask))
```

Outputs:

```
<class 'tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Tensor'>
```

I get the error at `mask = mask.numpy()`. I believe that it is due to it being a different type of tensor not an `EagerTensor`, which supports `.numpy()`. The issue I have found is that most other ways of converting a tensor to a `np.array` were removed in TF2.0. How would one go about converting a tensor to a `np.array` given the scenario? Or should I just give up and attempt to find a different implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Use `tf.make_ndarray` to convert Tensorflow tensor to numpy.

**Sample code**

```
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.constant([[1,2,3],[4,5,6]])
proto_tensor = tf.make_tensor_proto(a)  # convert `tensor a` to a proto tensor
tf.make_ndarray(proto_tensor)
```

**output**

```
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]], dtype=int32)
```

In this case

```
mask = tf.make_ndarray(mask)
```